# have to access switchcase statement from another class using jtextfield

Tags: java, swing

In this below code section, I created two classes. First class is for designing in that I kept two jtextfields one is used to get String value another one is used to get numeric value. Second class is describing a function of string and numeric for to display the values in jtextfield. I can't to access string parameter in class a textfields.

If I will use this code it's accessing both the functions in each jtextfield. Please give a solution for this problem.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class valid implements KeyListener {
    perform1 per1=new perform1();
    String num1="Alpha";
    String num2="Numeric";
    String num3="Alphanumeric";
    JFrame fr=new JFrame();
    JPanel jp=new JPanel();
    JLabel label1=new JLabel("STUDENT NAME");
    JLabel label2=new JLabel("REG NO");
    JTextField text1=new JTextField(15);
    JTextField text2=new JTextField(15);
    public valid(){
        text1.addKeyListener(this);
        text2.addKeyListener(this);
        jp.add(label1);
        jp.add(text1);
        jp.add(label2);
        jp.add(text2);
        fr.add(jp);
        fr.setSize(450, 330);
        fr.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        per1.dis(text1, e, num1);
        per1.dis(text2, e, num2);
    }
    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
        new valid();
    }

}
class perform1{
    public void dis(JTextField PTxtCtrl,KeyEvent PKeyvalue,String PTempStr){
        JLabel error=new JLabel();
        String TmpCurntStr;
        String TmpConvStr;
        value val = value.valueOf(PTempStr);

        switch(val){
            case Alpha:
                if(PKeyvalue.getKeyChar()>='a'&& PKeyvalue.getKeyChar()<='z'){
                    TmpCurntStr=PTxtCtrl.getText();
                    TmpConvStr=TmpCurntStr.toUpperCase();
                    PTxtCtrl.setText(TmpConvStr);
                   }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(error,"Enter only alpha");
                }

                break;
            case Numeric:
                if(PKeyvalue.getKeyChar()>='0'&& PKeyvalue.getKeyChar()<='9'){
                    TmpCurntStr=PTxtCtrl.getText();
                    System.out.println("hai");
                 }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(error,"Enter only numeric");
                }
                break;
            case Alphanumeric:
                break;
        }
    }
    enum value{
        Alpha,
        Numeric,
        Alphanumeric    
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the naming conventions, variable names should start with lower case letter, following the convention makes it easier to read you code (and avoids the confusion in the HTML markup)

Comment: @BinyaminSharet I agree with you, but I also notice that all the parameters are prefixed with P which leads me to believe OP is being instructed by someone who insists on Hungarian notation, and keeping in line with most Hungarian notators I know, he would probably get marks down for not conforming to whatever standards the instructor decided.

Comment: @glowcode - I was not aware of that. seems reasonable.

Comment: @glowcoder a bad teacher is no excuse for doing things the wrong way, not even for violating conventions

Comment: @kleopatra That's naive. In the real world you have to maintain code written by other people. I'm on a team of 10 programmers and I'm the only one who doesn't want to use Hungarian notation. It's true. I don't like it one bit. But as programmers we HAVE to adapt.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using the same KeyListener for both text fields. Instead, use a different one for each text field as shown below:

```
class valid  {
    perform1 per1=new perform1();
    String num1="Alpha";
    String num2="Numeric";
    String num3="Alphanumeric";
    JFrame fr=new JFrame();
    JPanel jp=new JPanel();
    JLabel label1=new JLabel("STUDENT NAME");
    JLabel label2=new JLabel("REG NO");
    JTextField text1=new JTextField(15);
    JTextField text2=new JTextField(15);
    public valid(){
        text1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                per1.dis(text1, e, num1);
            }

        });
        text2.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                per1.dis(text2, e, num2);
            }

        });
        jp.add(label1);
        jp.add(text1);
        jp.add(label2);
        jp.add(text2);
        fr.add(jp);
        fr.setSize(450, 330);
        fr.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
        new valid();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution would be to have two classes:

```
class performString {

    public void perform(JTextField PTxtCtrl,KeyEvent PKeyvalue) {
        // work on strings here
    }

}

class performNumeric {

    public void perform(JTextField PTxtCtrl,KeyEvent PKeyvalue) {
        // work on numerics here
    }

}
```

Then later on, you can do this

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == label1) per1.perform(text1, e);
    else if(e.getSource() == label2) per2.perform(text2, 2);
}
```

Comment: Ok, but i have to use more functions so i want to declare all functions in same class. then i accessing these functions in many classes, so i want these single class. please help me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Why do you want to put them all in the same class? They don't belong in the same class. They have entirely different behavior and should be in different classes. Even though the behavior looks like it's doing similar things, the amount of work required to make it actually reuse code instead of a giant switch statement is considerably more complicated than just using multiple classes. They do share a method signature, so they probably should have a backing interface.

Comment: If you *really* want to put them in the same class, you could have a `performString` method and a `performInteger` method and call them appropriately. I would recommend against it, but it will allow you to have them in the same class while at the same time keeping them separate so they don't get in eachother's way accidentally.

Comment: Please can you reply me how to solve because 6classes is accessing the same methods. so i need these functions in same class.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't make much sense, Ezilarasi; perhaps it's the language barrier. Could you try rephrasing what the problem is? Does it not work? What's the specific problem you're encountering?

Comment: My problem is i couldn't get the String functions, alphanumeric functions, numeric functions, making e-mail ID format function and date functions in the jtextfield properly. I am getting all the functions in each jtextfield, because that string variable is not accessing in the JtextField class

Comment: @kleopatra Those aren't my naming conventions. They're the naming conventions used by the OP. I'm staunchly anti-Hungarian, but that's what the OP is using and as I said in my comments on the original question, he is likely to lose points for not following them. And while it is entirely your prerogative to downvote on whatever criteria you feel necessary, I feel in this case that's a poor decision, as the bad naming convention is actually more useful than a good one in this specific case.